# Como hacer efecto de curva en el texto

Tags: html, css3

Quiero hacer una efecto en el texto cada vez que se carga la pagina, pero no se como buscarlo.

entonces me gustaría saber como se llama ese tipo de animación.

buscando en google encontré varios, pero ninguno es el que estoy buscando
https://www.creativosonline.org/blog/efectos-texto-css.html

Ejemplo de la animación

http://optimusdrone.co/

gracias

Comment: Hola Daniel busca en google text transitions css3 codepen.io te van a salir muchos ejemplos por ahi alguno cubre tu necesidad no te paso justo el q es porq estoy desde el celular y tengo mala conexion para q me carguen las paginas

Comment: okey voy a mirar gracias